# Get MBProgressHUD's progress from NSURL

Tags: ios, objective-c, nsurl, nsurlsession, mbprogresshud

I am trying to calculate the progress of my download method and show `MBProgressHUD`'s progress during file is downloading , but I don't know how to calculate the progress float ! here is my code :

```
- (IBAction)preview:(id)sender {

    HUD = [[MBProgressHUD alloc] initWithView:self.navigationController.view];
    [self.navigationController.view addSubview:HUD];

    // Set determinate mode
    HUD.mode = MBProgressHUDModeAnnularDeterminate;

    HUD.delegate = self;
    HUD.labelText = @"Loading";

    // myProgressTask uses the HUD instance to update progress
    [HUD showWhileExecuting:@selector(downloadDataFromMac) onTarget:self withObject:nil animated:YES];

}


- (void)downloadData {

    NSURLSessionConfiguration *configuration = [NSURLSessionConfiguration defaultSessionConfiguration];
    AFURLSessionManager *manager = [[AFURLSessionManager alloc] initWithSessionConfiguration:configuration];

    NSURL *URL = [NSURL URLWithString:pathWithData];
    NSURLRequest *request = [NSURLRequest requestWithURL:URL];

    NSURLSessionDownloadTask *downloadTask = [manager downloadTaskWithRequest:request progress:nil destination:^NSURL *(NSURL *targetPath, NSURLResponse *response) {

        NSURL *documentsDirectoryURL = [[NSFileManager defaultManager] URLForDirectory:NSDocumentDirectory inDomain:NSUserDomainMask appropriateForURL:nil create:NO error:nil];
        return [documentsDirectoryURL URLByAppendingPathComponent:[response suggestedFilename]];


    } completionHandler:^(NSURLResponse *response, NSURL *filePath, NSError *error) {

        NSLog(@"File downloaded to: %@", filePath);

        //Hide HUD
        [HUD hide:YES];

            self.documentInteractionController = [UIDocumentInteractionController interactionControllerWithURL:filePath];

            [self.documentInteractionController setDelegate:self];

            [self.documentInteractionController presentPreviewAnimated:YES];

        }];


    [downloadTask resume];

}
```

EDITED :

```
- (void)downloadDataFromMac {

    NSURLSessionConfiguration *configuration = [NSURLSessionConfiguration defaultSessionConfiguration];
    AFURLSessionManager *manager = [[AFURLSessionManager alloc] initWithSessionConfiguration:configuration];

    NSURL *URL = [NSURL URLWithString:pathWithData];
    NSURLRequest *request = [NSURLRequest requestWithURL:URL];

    NSProgress *progress;
    NSURLSessionDownloadTask *downloadTask = [manager downloadTaskWithRequest:request progress:&progress destination:^NSURL *(NSURL *targetPath, NSURLResponse *response) {

        [progress addObserver:self
                   forKeyPath:@"fractionCompleted"
                      options:NSKeyValueObservingOptionNew
                      context:NULL];

        NSURL *documentsDirectoryURL = [[NSFileManager defaultManager] URLForDirectory:NSDocumentDirectory inDomain:NSUserDomainMask appropriateForURL:nil create:NO error:nil];

        return [documentsDirectoryURL URLByAppendingPathComponent:[response suggestedFilename]];



    } completionHandler:^(NSURLResponse *response, NSURL *filePath, NSError *error) {

        NSLog(@"File downloaded to: %@", filePath);

        //Hide HUD
        [HUD hide:YES];

            self.documentInteractionController = [UIDocumentInteractionController interactionControllerWithURL:filePath];

            [self.documentInteractionController setDelegate:self];

            [self.documentInteractionController presentPreviewAnimated:YES];

        }];


    [downloadTask resume];

}



- (void)observeValueForKeyPath:(NSString *)keyPath ofObject:(id)object change:(NSDictionary *)change context:(void *)context{
    if ([keyPath isEqualToString:@"fractionCompleted"]) {
        NSProgress *progress = (NSProgress *)object;
        NSLog(@"Progress… %f", progress.fractionCompleted);
        //do something with your progress here, for eg :
        //but dont forget to first make HUD a class property so you can update it
        [HUD setProgress:progress.fractionCompleted];

    } else {
        [super observeValueForKeyPath:keyPath ofObject:object change:change context:context];
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use **RSNetworkKit**. It has all handy methods for all network related calls, download and upload files with progress. It has internally implemented AFNetworking.

https://github.com/rushisangani/RSNetworkKit

**RSDownlaodManager** has a method to download any file with progress
you can simple use like this.

```
[[RSDownloadManager sharedManager] downloadWithURL:@"URLString" downloadProgress:^(NSNumber *progress) {

// show progress using HUD here
// must use main thread to show progress or update UI.

} success:^(NSURLResponse *response, NSURL *filePath) {

} andFailure:^(NSError *error) {

}];
```

Comment: I downloaded the framework but and follow installation but still get this error `RSNetworkKit.h not found` !!!!!!!!!

Comment: have you tried with import <RSNetworkKit/RSNetworkKit.h>?

Comment: Yes ! It seems you are the developer , would you please send me a sample project ? Why did you make the installation so complicated ?!

Comment: Yes, I've updated the installation steps. Please check and let me know if u still found any issue. Its easy!!. Just make a lib folder in project's folder, put frameworks into that folder, drag and drop that framework to your project and set some flags in project settings. Thats it!!

Comment: Example is also added for reference. Thanks!!

Comment: Would you please email me ? I have 2 questions : `me[at]momeks.com` , I would be really grateful.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/103031/discussion-between-iosenthusiatic-and-mc-lover).

Answer (score 1):

You can add an NSProgress property to the NSURLSessionDownloadTask definition, and then you can observe that property using KVO.  So just before you create the download task, create the property and add it to the definition, like this :

```
NSProgress *progress;
NSURLSessionDownloadTask *downloadTask = [manager downloadTaskWithRequest:request progress:&progress destination:^NSURL *(NSURL *targetPath, NSURLResponse *response) {

    NSURL *documentsDirectoryURL = [[NSFileManager defaultManager] URLForDirectory:NSDocumentDirectory inDomain:NSUserDomainMask appropriateForURL:nil create:NO error:nil];

    return [documentsDirectoryURL URLByAppendingPathComponent:[response suggestedFilename]];



} completionHandler:^(NSURLResponse *response, NSURL *filePath, NSError *error) {

    NSLog(@"File downloaded to: %@", filePath);

    //Hide HUD
    [HUD hide:YES];

        self.documentInteractionController = [UIDocumentInteractionController interactionControllerWithURL:filePath];

        [self.documentInteractionController setDelegate:self];

        [self.documentInteractionController presentPreviewAnimated:YES];

    }];

[progress addObserver:self
        forKeyPath:@"fractionCompleted"
           options:NSKeyValueObservingOptionNew
           context:NULL];
[downloadTask resume];
```

Then to observe that progress property as it changes, add this method to your class :

```
- (void)observeValueForKeyPath:(NSString *)keyPath ofObject:(id)object change:(NSDictionary *)change context:(void *)context{
if ([keyPath isEqualToString:@"fractionCompleted"]) {
    NSProgress *progress = (NSProgress *)object;
    NSLog(@"Progress… %f", progress.fractionCompleted);
    //do something with your progress here, for eg :
    //but dont forget to first make HUD a class property so you can update it
    [self.hud setProgress:progress.fractionCompleted];

} else {
    [super observeValueForKeyPath:keyPath ofObject:object change:change context:context];
}
}
```

Comment: Thank you but I get this error `'NSProgress *__strong *' to parameter of incompatible type 'void (^ _Nullable)(NSProgress * _Nonnull __strong)'`

Comment: Can you post your code for where you defined the NSURLSessionDownloadTask?  (the whole thing with the blocks etc)

Comment: It's is so weird !!! I just checked every similar questions and all answers was the same ! with no error !!! why I am getting this error !!!

Comment: Sorry Mc.Lover, been away.  Its because you are registering for KVO within the block.  I should have been more specific.  The line of code [progress addObserver.. ] needs to go outside that definition.  So move that line of code outside of the definition, down to the bottom, just before you call [downloadTask resume]

Comment: @LukeSmith I used your code but still error  'NSProgress *__strong *' to parameter of incompatible type 'void (^ _Nullable)(NSProgress * _Nonnull __strong)'. Please Help Me.

Comment: @EktaMakadiya make sure the line of code where you register for KVO - `[progress addObserver..` is somewhere else apart from where the download is defined.  If that line of code is WITHIN the blocks there - it doesnt work.